# Filter values in drop down of AttributeInspector (ESRI JS API 3.24)

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis-js-api, esri-javascript-api

I am using [AttributeInpector](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/attributeinspector-amd.html) for displaying attributes associated with a Polygon in Feature Layer in ArcGIS ESRI.

I want to filter values in drop down for an attribute which can have one value out of the multiple possible values, displayed in AttributeInspector based on selected value of other drop down.

Is it possible to filter out values in AttributeInspector?

Are there any built-in alternatives of AttributeInspector available with which this can be achieved?

Comment: By "filter values in drop down" - can you please clarify what you mean here? Do you mean you have an attribute column that is a domain (list of options) that you'd like to change that dropdown to have fewer options? Perhaps adding an example might help.

Comment: Yes, I have two columns that are domain objects (list of options) and when user selects value in one of them, the domain values in other column (or attribute) should be filtered.

Comment: can you share some code you wrote ?